# How can I set the encoding of an XML document in ColdFusion?

Tags: xml, character-encoding, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am creating and XML object using `<cfxml>`:

```
<cfxml variable="LOCAL.Xml">
    <Root>
        <Header>
            <CompanyName>ACME</CompanyName>
            <AccountNumber>ACM1234</AccountNumber>
            <FileTimeStamp>2020-05-19{T}22:13:51</FileTimeStamp>
            <TimeZone>EDT</TimeZone>
        </Header>
    </Root>
</cfxml>
```

When I convert it to a String, the XML declaration is added to the top with `encoding="UTF-8"`. How do I specify a different encoding using CF11?

I've tried `<cfprocessingdirective encoding="iso-8859-1">`.

I've tried `<cfheader name="content-disposition" charset="iso-8859-1" value="attachment; filename=file.xml" />`.

I've tried converting it to Binary with encoding "iso-8859-1" and then back to string.

Every time I get the same result.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is a header added to the response? I would try looking at some header changes at server level. What webserver are you using? In case you are using apache, I would check mod_headers or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is copied from the documentation for `cfxml` posted here - [CFXML](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-u-z/cfxml.html)

> To convert an XML document object back into a string, use the `ToString` function, at which time ColdFusion automatically prepends the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` XML declaration.
>
> To change the declaration to specify another encoding, use the `Replace` function. To specify the encoding of the text that is returned to a browser or other application, use the `cfcontent` tag. The following example illustrates this process:

```
<cfprocessingdirective suppressWhiteSpace = "yes">
<cfcontent type="text/xml; charset=utf-16">
<cfxml variable="xmlobject">
    <breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name quantity="50">Belgian Waffles</name>
        <description>Our famous Belgian Waffles</description>
    </food>
    </breakfast_menu>
</cfxml>

<!--- <cfdump var="#xmlobject#">--->

<cfset myvar=toString(xmlobject)>
<cfset mynewvar=replace(myvar, "UTF-8", "utf-16")>

<!---<cfdump var="#mynewvar#">--->

<cfoutput>#mynewvar#</cfoutput>
</cfprocessingdirective>
```

> The cfprocessingdirective tag prevents ColdFusion from putting white space characters in front of the XML declaration.

Notice the mention that "*ColdFusion automatically prepends the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` XML declaration*"

And their recommended method to change that using "*the `Replace` function*". So for you the replace would become:

```
<cfset myvar=toString(xmlobject)>
<cfset mynewvar=replace(myvar, "UTF-8", "iso-8859-1")>
```

And you would also want to change the `cfcontent` tag as:

```
<cfcontent type="text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: I did see the documentation with the idea to use Replace(), but this seems so kludgy. "encoding" is essentially an attribute of an object property (the xml declaration), so it should be "settable", but, I agree this is the best solution. Thank you for the excellent explanation!